# Prove $\sin x + \sin 3x + \cdots + \sin(2n-1)x = \frac{\sin^2 nx}{\sin x}$ is true

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

> If $x \neq k\pi$ and $n \in \mathbb Z$ then prove $$\sin x + \sin 3x + \cdots + \sin(2n-1)x = \frac{\sin^2 nx}{\sin x}$$

So I stumbled into this problem in my textbook in the complex numbers chapter. It is an optional problem, so the teacher won't explain it to us. I have no idea on how to approach it in the first place. Could anyone please give me a clue on how to begin solving it?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a complex numbers proof, note the LHS is the imaginary part
of
$$S=e^{ix}+e^{3ix}+\cdots+e^{(2n-1)ix}.$$
That's a geometric progression:
$$S=e^{ix}\frac{e^{2in x}-1}{e^{2ix}-1}=e^{inx}\frac{e^{inx}
-e^{-inx}}{e^{i x}-e^{-ix}}
=e^{inx}\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}=(\cos nx+i\sin nx)
\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}.$$

Comment: @MariaMazur Not any more!

Comment: I bet you have writen somwhere both solution?

Answer (score 3):

If we make an induction proof then it is enought to prove: $$\sin(2n+1)x =  \frac{\sin^2 (n+1)x}{\sin x} -\frac{\sin^2 nx}{\sin x} $$ or

$$\sin(2n+1)x \cdot \sin x=  \Big(\sin (n+1)x -\sin nx\Big)\Big(\sin (n+1)x +\sin nx\Big)  $$

Now, since: 
$$\sin (n+1)x -\sin nx = 2\cos {(2n+1)x\over 2}\sin{x\over 2}$$
and
 $$\sin (n+1)x +\sin nx = 2\sin {(2n+1)x\over 2}\cos{x\over 2}$$

and using $$ \sin2\alpha = 2\sin \alpha\cos \alpha $$ we are done.